# How to set the class of value returned by __new__ without using super?

Tags: python, factory

I want `B` to be a subclass of some class `A`, and I want to override `A.__new__`<sup>1</sup>.  Typically, my code for this would have this basic structure:

```
class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, ...):
        ret = super(B, cls).__new__(cls, ...)

        # modify ret as needed

        return ret  # type(ret) is cls

    # ...
```

In this way, `type(B(...))` is indeed `B`.  (Note: the ellipses in `super(B, cls).__new__(cls, ...)` need not represent the same items as those represented by the ellipses in `B.__new__`'s signature.)

But suppose now that I want to use the value returned by some *factory method/function* `A_Factory` (which returns an object of type `A`) as the starting value for the variable `ret` in the constructor.  If I simply coded this:

```
class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, ...):
        ret = A_Factory(...)

        # modify ret as needed

        return ret  # type(ret) is A
```

...then `type(B(...))` would be `A`, not `B`.

What's the correct way to set class of `ret` in the second version of `B.__new__` above so that, `type(B(...))` is `B`, and, more generally, so that, for any direct or indirect subclass `C` of `B`, `type(C(...))` is `C`?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I know that one normally does not need to override a parent class's `__new__`, but here I'm interested in the uncommon case where one needs to.</sup>

Comment: Are you adamant on using `__new__` or would you be open to an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`__class__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__) attribute of the instance to be the `cls` passed into `__new__`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2

def A_Factory():
    return A() 

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls):
        ret = A_Factory()

        ret.__class__ = cls  # Override the class.

        return ret  # type(ret) is cls

class C(B):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B() 
    print(b.x)
    print(type(b))
    print(isinstance(b, B)) 
    print(isinstance(b, A))
    c = C()
    print(type(C))
```

Output:

```
2
<class '__main__.B'>
True
True
<class '__main__.C'>
```

There are some limitations to this, though. The [commit that added the ability to assign to `__class__`](http://python-checkins.git.net/2001-September/021629.html) lists them:

> Make `__class__` assignment possible, when the object structures are the
>   same.  I hope the test for structural equivalence is stringent enough.
>   It only allows the assignment if the old and new types:
>
> - have the same basic size
> - have the same item size
> - have the same dict offset
> - have the same weaklist offset
> - have the same GC flag bit
> - have a common base that is the same except for maybe the dict and   weaklist (which may have been added separately at the same offsets
>     in both types)

They also need to have the identical `__slots__`, if you have that defined on either class. In practice, this usually just means that both classes need to be implemented in Python. Trying to do it with a regular Python class and `int` or `tuple` or something else implemented in C isn't likely to work.